# Typecasting a String into an Int within a for loop

Tags: python

How would I store the position variable i as an int so that I can play with that particular position within a string.

```
sentence = input()
for i in sentence:
    if i == " ":
        j = int(i) #this line is throwing an error 
        print (sentence[0:j])
```

Comment: To be clear, you want to get each character in the string by its index? so if sentence is "abcd", sentence[0] = "a" sentence[1] = b etc?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to know the position of any spaces in a string 
ie- in the string hi hi 
     i want j to equal 2

Comment: ok, so in if i==" ", just do sentence.index(i) and that will give you the index of spaces...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two flaws within your code:

```
if i == " ":
    j = int(i)
```

So you check whether `i` is a space character, in which case you want to convert that space into a number. Of course that’s not going to work—what number is that space supposed to mean?

The other flaw is the reason why you have a space character there. You say that you want to use the position, or index, of the character. But your for loop does something different than what you expect: `for x in sequence` will iterate over every element `x` within that sequence. In case of a string sequence, you will get every character—not an index though.

For example:

```
>>> for x in 'foo':
        print(x)

f
o
o
```

As you can see, it prints the characters, not the indexes.

You can use `enumerate()` for this though. Enumerate will enumerate over a sequence giving you the value *and* the index it appeared at:

```
>>> for i, x in enumerate('foo'):
        print(i, x)

0 f
1 o
2 o
```

So you get the index too.

In your case, your code would look like this then:

```
sentence = input()
for i, x in enumerate(sentence):
    if x == " ":
        print(sentence[0:i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `enumerate`

```
for k, v in enumerate(sentence):
   if v == " ":
     print (sentence[0:k])
```

You are casting space char to int. Of course does not work.

```
>>> int(' ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Answer (score 0):

If You try to find position of `' '` use `sentence.index(' ')`:

```
sentence = input()
try:
    i = sentence.index(' ')
    print (sentence[0:j])
except ValueError:
    pass
```